# Sentences begin with Has and Is

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

I would like to know the difference between the following two sentences

> Has he finished reading the book?

and

> Is he finished reading the book?

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: I don't think the latter is correct. I expect a preposition "with" with a noun phrase complement.

Comment: @user178049 So when does `Has` and `Is` are used at the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: They are used in a question. (Google subject-auxiliary inversion.) But I think "finished" is a verb in the first sentence and "finished" is an adjective in the second sentence."Finished"when used as an adjective normally takes a preposition "with". Btw, I'm not a grammarian, so I'm not very sure about my explanation.

Comment: I would forget the adjective idea here. To be finished doing something is a verb. To finish doing something is also a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these mean much the same thing.  It's really just two ways to ask the same question.  The first asks whether a particular *action* is complete, while the second asks whether a particular *condition* is true.

A similar example

> Have you finished eating?
>   Are you finished eating?

In much the same way (with slightly different grammar)

> Have the children come home from school?
>   Are the children home from school?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is my second sentence correct?

Comment: Yes, it's fine.  I think it sounds odd to some people because of the context -- it's not entirely natural to ask "is he finished reading the book?" while it is natural to ask "are you finished eating dinner?"  More natural is "Is he finished *with* the book?"

Comment: @ `Has he finished reading the book?` can be also considered correct grammatically?

Comment: @user75ponic  Yes, it's the normal use of the present perfect.  "Has he come home?" "Has he visited his grandmother recently?" "Has he washed the dishes?" etc.